# What is the expected number of days for you to escape the well?

Tags: probability, expected-value

The problem is as follows:
[image: The well with the stages of getting out]

Above is the well which we are trying to escape. It has **four** levels, and to escape we need to make it to the top. Each day you have a **1/2** probability to ascend to the next level or else you will descend to the previous level. Let S and F represent successes and failures respectively. So as an example, you could escape the well with {S, S, F, S, S, S}, or with {F, F, S, S, S, S}, taking 6 days on either of these attempts. How many days can we expect it to take to escape? Once we have solved that problem, what is the solution for a well with **n** levels, and **p** probability to ascend?

Comment: What have you tried?  You have a Markov chain with a few states.  Assign a variable to the expected time from each step.  Write equations to connect the values at neighboring steps.

Comment: Besides typing the text of your exercice and (well ?) drawing the well, what have you done ? Are you awaiting others to solve your issue from A to Z ?.

Answer (score 2):

Hint.

Let $n$, and $p$ be the number of levels and the probability to reach the next level, respectively. Let $E_k$ be expected number of attempts for escaping the well from the $k$-th level.

Then for $n>1$:
$$
\begin{align}
E_1&=1+pE_2+(1-p)E_1,\\
E_k&=1+pE_{k+1}+(1-p)E_{k-1},\quad 1< k<n,\\
E_n&=1+(1-p)E_{n-1}.
\end{align}
$$

Solve the equations and find $E_1$.

> It can be easily verified that $E_k=(n-k+1)(n+k)$ solves the problem for $p=\frac12$. Particularly $E_1=n(n+1)$.

Comment: In my version the escape is at the $(n+1)$-th level. This agrees also with definition used by OP.